# Criar uma coluna no Mysql que automaticamente divida os valores outras duas colunas

Tags: mysql, sql

Galera preciso que me expliquem como posso fazer com que semelhante ao que acontece no Excel  eu possa criar uma coluna no Mysql que divida os valores de outras duas colunas. Algo como coluna 1 / coluna 2= coluna 3.

Por exemplo tenho duas colunas e varias linhas, na primeira linhas na coluna1 eu teria o valor 4, na primeira linha na coluna2 eu teria o valor 2, na primeira linha da coluna3 seria o valor de 4/2

Comment: Não consegui entender. Dê algum exemplo

Comment: Por exemplo tenho duas colunas e varias linhas, na primeira linhas na coluna1 eu teria o valor 4, na primeira linha na coluna2 eu teria o valor 2, na primeira linha da coluna3 seria o valor de 4/2.

Comment: Ok, coloque isso na pergunta. Você pode [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/56662/edit). Outra coisa, o que vc quer é um código SQL que faça isso? Ou outra coisa? (coloque isso na pergunta também)

Comment: SELECT campo1, campo2, campo1/campo2 AS Divisao FROM nomeTabela

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partir da versão 5.7 é possível criar [colunas calculadas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-generated-columns). A sintaxe (simplificada) é a seguinte:

```
col_name data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)
```

Aplicado ao seu caso seria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (
   campo1 DOUBLE,
   campo2 DOUBLE,
   divisao DOUBLE AS (campo1/campo2)
);
```

Caso utilize uma versão anterior existem 3 soluções possíveis:

**1 - Fazer o cálculo no *SELECT*:**

Na indicação das colunas que este deve retornar, podem ser definidas outras que sejam calculadas em função das colunas da tabela.

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, campo1/campo2 AS nomeQueQuiserDar FROM tabela
```

<sub>Com a cláusula *AS* pode dar o nome que quiser ao resultado calculado.</sub>

Veja no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd4fe/1)

**2 - Criar uma *VIEW* com o campo calculado:**

```
CREATE VIEW nome_view AS
SELECT campo1, campo2, campo1/campo2 AS divisao FROM tabela;
```

Use a *VIEW* em vez da tabela no *SELECT*:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, divisao FROM nome_view
```

**3 - Criar um *TRIGGER* que calcule o resultado e guarde numa coluna da tabela:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER nome_trigger AFTER INSERT
ON tabela
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.campo3 = NEW.campo1 / NEW.campo2
```

Tem de criar o campo3 na tabela antes de criar o *TRIGGER*.

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD campo3 DOUBLE
```

Se a tabela já tiver dados, antes de criar o *TRIGGER*, actualize o campo3 em função dos dados existentes.

```
UPDATE tabela SET campo3 = campo1/campo2
```

Caso os valores dos campo1 e campo2 possam vir a ser alterados, será necessário criar um outro *TRIGGER* para refletir essa alteração no campo3.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE
ON tabela
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.campo3 = NEW.campo1 / NEW.campo2
```

Comment: No TRIGGER eu tenho que criar a coluna3 antes?

Comment: Sim , a coluna deve existir, a trigger só faz o trabalho de calcular a coluna.

Comment: O valor fica definido como NULL

Comment: Adicionei mais detalhes à resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Seria também possível criar uma  coluna calculada, por exemplo:

```
Create table ( campo1 double, campo2 double, campo3 as ((campo1/campo2) as double));
```

Esse tipo de tabela pode interferir no processamento para isso verifique outro tipo de tabela persisted...

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: A pergunta se refere ao MySQL onde só a partir da versão 5.7 é possível criar [colunas calculadas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-generated-columns). Note também que a sintaxe que utilizou não é de MySQL.